# React, Solidity, Ethereum: I can't create a React button that correctly calls a smart contract function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, solidity

So, I am currently developing a back-end and a front-end to a dApp.

The back-end is my Solidity-written smart contract, which works perfectly fine when I use and test it on Truffle. 
I've created a struct, and in the contract I use a list of this struct.

```
struct Offre {
    address manager;
    string content;
    uint number;
}

Offre[] public offres;
```

One of my function returns the content of any given element of this list.

```
function getOfferNumber(uint i) public view returns (string r) {
        return offres[i].content;
}
```

So, I've tested this function in Truffle and, as expected, it returns the string I want it to return.

Now, I am trying to create a button in React where I can : indicate a number i, click the button to get the content of the offer number i.

In my App.js, I have my state :

```
state = {
        ...
        number: '',
        offerToCheck: '',
    };
```

The function I'm calling with my button goes like this

```
checkMessage() {
        const offerToCheck = DemandeOffre.methods.getOfferNumber(this.state.number).call();
        this.setState({ offerToCheck });
    }
```

where this.state.number is the number I am giving him in the render():

```
 <div>
            <label>Check Offer</label>
                <input
                    value={this.state.number}
                    onChange={event => this.setState({ number: event.target.value })}
                />
         </div>
         <button onClick={this.checkMessage}>Check</button>
         <p> The offer you checked goes as follows : {this.state.offerToCheck}. </p>
```

When I try to use it like that, I get an `"TypeError: this is undefined"` error by React on the `const offerToCheck = DemandeOffre.methods.getOfferNumber(this.state.number).call();` line.

I've tried various thing, like for example using a bind(this). When I do this, clicking on the button simply gets me to a blank page.

I am not really familiar with react, so I don't know if I've explained my problem thoroughly. Hope I will find a solution.

Comment: you should use `<button onClick={this.checkMessage.bind(this)}>Check</button>`. The reason it displays a blank page on click i think is a different issue. It has to do with `DemandeOffre.methods.getOfferNumber(this.state.number).call();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `this` to not be undefined you can define the function like so:`checkMessage = () => {...}`. Also, the call to the contract returns a promise so to get the value from there you have to use `await` or `.then()`, you can read more [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-call). The way you do it now the `offerToCheck` variable will not have the correct value when you use it to set the state of the component.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Using .then(res => this.setState({ offerToCheck: res })) solved my issue. Thanks again.